# JavaFX How to get all values of one column from TableView?

Tags: javafx

I would like to get all data of one column from my TableView after Button click.

I found this code

```
    TablePosition pos = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().get(0);
int row = pos.getRow();

// Item here is the table view type:
Item item = table.getItems().get(row);

TableColumn col = pos.getTableColumn();

// this gives the value in the selected cell:
String data = (String) col.getCellObservableValue(item).getValue();
```

But this is code for selected cell and i have button and all cells of one column.

Can you help me pls?
Thankyou.

Answer (score 8):

Just do the same thing for all elements of `table.getItems()`:

```
TableColumn<MyDataType, String> column = ... ; // column you want

List<String> columnData = new ArrayList<>();
for (MyDataType item : table.getItems()) {
    columnData.add(col.getCellObservableValue(item).getValue());
}
```

where `MyDataType` is the data type of the `TableView`.

Comment: But what I put into variable column? ......... TableColumn<MyDataType, String> column = ... What

Comment: The column for which you want to get the values.